# xamarin mvvm IsBusy first run

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

i've no idea why at the first run of the app the ActivityIndicator is running

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>


public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return _isBusy; }
            set
            {
                _isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
            }
        }
```

all samples i've found are doing the same...
if i also set IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy} all is working fine but i just want to understand why all samples are working without the IsVisible property set.

thanks

Comment: What is the value of `_isBusy` initially?

Comment: not set, default in c# is false,  private bool _isBusy; also tried private bool _isBusy = false; same result

Comment: Where do you set the BindingContext?

Comment: xaml  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:LoginViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext> same as in the samples. it is working if i change IsBusy by button click to true and then to false. its only not working at start